# I'm and bit confused what is wrong with my loop? It goes through my two images but wont go through my last third one

Tags: python, arrays, background-image

This is the code if you would like to just look at it. By the way I am using regular python on trinket.io

[link for image, since i cant embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tUMd.png)

Comment: You should copy the text from your image into the description. Use backticks to make a code block.

Comment: I believe there is an indentation problem with your code.

Comment: please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You have indentation issue for accessing first image go with index 0 and for second image go for index 1 and for third image go with index 3

```
// for first image    
background.bgpic(my_maps[0])
// for second image    
background.bgpic(my_maps[1])
// for third image    
background.bgpic(my_maps[2])
```